# Python: If statement - test against multiple things

Tags: python

I've written this same kind of if statement line 20 or 30 times over the last few months, and I'm seeking a more efficient way to write it:

```
if type(_dt) == dt.date or type(_dt) == dt.datetime:
```

or more generally: `if x = y, or x = z:`

so I thought I'd try this in the interpreter:

```
In:    if 1 == 2 or 1:
        print('yay')

Out: yay
```

I was hoping someone could explain to me why this worked, and if this is the right way to do an inf statement like;

```
if x == y or z:
```

Thanks!

Comment: In this case you could do `if type(_dt) in (dt.date, dt.datetime):`

Comment: Nice, I like that!  any reason a tuple vs list?

Comment: For the second part of the question check [Why does "a == x or y or z" always evaluate to True? How can I compare "a" to all of those?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20002503/4046632)

Comment: For tuple vs list, that will be basically the same so up to you. If the list got very long you could instead use a set which has faster containment check so like `{dt.date, dt.datetime}` but for only a few elements either tuple, set, or list will all act basically the same in terms of performance

Comment: It didn't work. It simply isn't an *error*, and it's behavior coincides with your expected behavior for *this* example. Try `0 == 1 or 0` instead.

Comment: Or the other way round: `0 == 1 or 2`.